# FirebaseML Vision with SwiftPM

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-machine-learning

I was installing Firebase via Swift package manager trying to use FirebaseMLVision framework.  I was wondering if this was removed or hasn't been added yet to Swiftpm.  I selected Firebase, Firebase auth, and FirebaseMLModuleDownloader and couldn't find them.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Swift Package Manager support for Firebase is pretty new, and features are added slowly. It indeed looks like the Firebase Machine Learning packages have not been added to SPM yet.

Keep an eye on the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) to see when Swift Package Manager support is added to more products.

If you'd like to help, I'm quite sure the team would welcome PRs too on the [Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk). :)

---

Update: I just saw this issue ["Firebase ML: Support for Swift Package Manager"](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6362) was marked as done, so you might want to check that.

Comment: I found that issue as well but I wasn't sure if FirebaseMLModuleDownloader encompassed all of the ML packages or if it was just one and I needed to wait for the rest of them to be add